# xcode error: failed to emit precompiled header

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I am trying to continuous integrate IOS App using while building.
Jenkins:2.100
xcode:9.2

Below Build error:

/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/PHOENIX_IOS_PRODUCTION/PhoenixiOS/PhoenixiOS-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: error: 'NewRelicAgent/NewRelic.h' file not found

## import "NewRelicAgent/NewRelic.h"

error: failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/PHOENIX_IOS_PRODUCTION/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixiOS/PrecompiledHeaders/PhoenixiOS-Bridging-Header-swift_3OXBDDB6OLUKX-clang_9521NPKFGEEZ.pch' for bridging header '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/PHOENIX_IOS_PRODUCTION/PhoenixiOS/PhoenixiOS-Bridging-Header.h'

Please give me suggestions on how to solve it.

Comment: having the same problem ... ugh

Comment: @Ronaldoh1  are you using Aws Code pipeline?. i have solution for it?

Comment: I had the same issue and it was resolved by going to Framework Search Paths and ensuring all of the values were in quotes " ". Just an idea for anyone else with this issue